# XJAX Reusing XMLHttp Object

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I've got a problem when trying to reuse an `XMLHttp` request object. I'm trying to incorporate AJAX into a site!

See my code below:

```php
var XMLHttp = createXMLHttpRequestObject();
function createXMLHttpRequestObject() {
  var xmlHTTP;

  //First to deal with Internet Explorer >:(
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    try {
      xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    catch (e) {
      xmlHTTP = false;
    }
  } else {
    try {
      xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
      xmlHTTP = false;
    }
  }

  if (!xmlHTTP)
    alert("Oops! Someone just unplugged the internet!");
  else
    return xmlHTTP;

}// XMLHttpRequest

function getAboutMe() {
  if (XMLHttp.readyState == 0 || XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
    XMLHttp.open("GET", "http://repairiphonesuk.com/rachael/AJAX/getAboutMe.php", true);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse('AboutMe');
    XMLHttp.send();
  } else {
    setTimeout(getAboutMe(), 1000);
    alert("no");
  }
}

function getHome() {
  if (XMLHttp.readyState == 0 || XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
    XMLHttp.open("GET", "http://repairiphonesuk.com/rachael/AJAX/getHome.php", true);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse('home');
    XMLHttp.send();
  } else {
    setTimeout(getHome(), 1000);
    alert("no");
  }
}


function handleServerResponse(from) {
  if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4 && XMLHttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("displayContent").innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText;
    if (from === 'home') {
      document.getElementById('displayContent').style.backgroundColor=transparent;
    }
  } else if (XMLHttp.status = 404) {
  }
}
```

When removing the `getHome()` function and the parameter to the handle request it works! Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: you have memory collision potensial here, i'm guessing you just set these off by calling one after another however if you server lags or anything like this then you risk the timing moving and them trying to use the same variable at the same time this is a big no no you could do it if you created them as seperate variable scopes but i'm still unsure why your trying to reuse the same viable the browsers memory cleaner is far better than you think and overrighting the same variable will be exactly the same as you using the different ones for each

Comment: oh and on another note to keep your code less confusing there is a far better way to get an universal AJAX call that everyone can understand
it's on this link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest under `heading Support in Internet Explorer versions 5, 5.5, and 6`

Answer (score 0):

`onreadystatechange` takes a function assignment, what you're doing is calling a function and assigning the return to `onreadystatechange`. Correct this by wrapping your code in an anonymous function.

```
XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function (){handleServerResponse('home')};
```

`setTimeout` takes a function as the first argument, what your doing is calling the function, basically the same thing with `onreadystatechange`, since `getHome` isn't taking any arguments just pass the function itself

```
setTimeout(getHome, 1000);
```

Comment: This still wont work how the OP is trying to using the same viable for 2 Ajax calls apart from the fact that AJAX can be ASYNC and SYNC so he risks having a collision in writing the memory for each object they need moving out of the global scope to prevent the collision. if one page request get's it's content it fire the readystatechange code but just as that has happened the other request has recive it's content it will collide and cause untold problems with the code

Comment: so would you recommend just having separate Javascript files with different XMTHttp objects and its own handle, createXMLHttpObject...etc methods?